# Combinatorial Limit as a sum

Tags: integration, combinatorics, limits, summation, binomial-coefficients

I have been trying to solve the following problem through ideas of limit as a sum.
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{(k+3)(n^k)}$$
I tried to resolve the binomial coefficient into $$\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{k+3}=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)\binom{n+3}{k+3}}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$$
That way, I tried to multiply and divide the expression with $n^3$taking out the denominator but I couldn't solve any further.
The solution showed a direct result of this being equal to $$\int_0^1{x^2e^xdx}$$ I want to know the intermediate steps for reaching this integral. Please help...

Comment: The limits are $0,\infty$ right?

Comment: $\int_0^1{x^2e^x\,dx}$ and not an idefinite integral

Comment: Thanks Claude, you are right. I wasn't able to put the limits in the mathjax function form:)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

From the binomial theorem,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}kt^{k+2}=t^2(1+t)^n
$$
Integrating both sides from $0$ to $x$ with respect to $t$,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac1{k+3}\binom{n}k x^{k+3}=\int_0^x t^2(1+t)^n\,dt
$$
Now you just need to evaluate that integral, substitute $1/n$ for $x$, and finally multiply by $n^3$.